# How to change parameter name in datatable.net such as : "draw", "recordsTotal" , "recordsFiltered"

Tags: spring, parameters, datatables

I use `PagingAndSortingRepository` of Spring framework for my app. When Page interface in server response to client with parameter: `totalPages`, `totalElements`, `numberOfElements`,`size`. But client datatable jquery (datatable.net) needs `draw`, `recordsTotal` , `recordsFiltered` parameters.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you using server-side processing mode (`serverSide: true`)?

Comment: yes I am using "serverSide: true"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [**`ajax.dataSrc`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) callback for preprocessing the response :

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "path/to/server",
    dataSrc: function(json) {
       json['recordsTotal'] = json['totalElements'];
       json['recordsFiltered'] = json['numberOfElements'];
       return json;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. it worked. But I think : return json.data;

Comment: hey @baby_sama - sorry for the long delay. Maybe I am little slow, what do you mean? You can return `json.data` only of course, but why?

Comment: I use "return json", then no data display. I think "dataSrc" needs to point to parameter that contain objects to display. I try use "return json.data" it's OK.

Comment: I really don't understand parameter "draw". Both request parameter and response parameter have "draw". May you explain it to me. What is the purpose of this parameter?

Comment: and "return json.data", I think datatable need a parameter named "data" in response  that contains objects. In my response, parameter contains objects named "content". I think so.

Comment: @hungnv132 - well, mee too. As I understand it is a kind of ticket, if you have a system where data is loaded all the time, then `draw` is to ensure datataTables also show data in the same order as requested, a kind of synchronicity-check. But have really no firsthand experience either :(