# Datatables show info on records Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables to show a table with 10K records. I'm showing 2K records at a time. When the table is loaded I have records from 0 - 2000, then if the button "next2K" is clicked, it reinitialize a new table with records from 2000 - 4000 and so on. I'm using the "info" attribute at datatables like this :

```
"info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
```

My problem is that when I have the records from 2000 - 4000, the "info" is like this :

*Showing 1 to 10 of 2000 entries*

But I want to show : ***Showing 2001 to 2010 of 4000 entries***. Is there a way doing it using `_START_ , _END_ , _TOTAL_` ?

My code is :

```
language: {
    info:    totRecords
},
```

And how I calculate totRecords is :

```
var totRecords = '';

if(dSize >= 2000){
    totRecords = '_START_-_END_ of 2000+';
}
else{
    totRecords = '_START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_';
}
```

totRecords is a string, and "info" translates `_START_,_END_, _TOTAL_` to numbers.

Comment: can you share you full piece of code where you are setting values for _start_ and _End_ etc..

Comment: Are you using the server-side processing option from dataTables? Then take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32920620/1040225 - this instructs you how to manipulate the JSON created by your server side script, to manipulate / change parameters like recordsTotal etc. Otherwise, please set up a jsfiddle with an example or show more code.